# why use cpu_to_le32 for the DMA address but not for length? (in an example code in a book)

Tags: dma, pci

I was reading the book *Essential Linux Device Driver* (by Sreekrishnan Venkateswaran) and in Chapter 10 *Listing 10.5. Setting Up DMA Descriptors and Buffers*, I see

```c
/* Device-specific data structure for the Ethernet Function */
struct device_data {
  struct pci_dev *pdev; /* The PCI Device structure */
  struct net_device *ndev; /* The Net Device structure */
  void *dma_buffer_rx; /* Kernel virtual address of the receive descriptor */
  dma_addr_t dma_bus_rx; /* Bus address of the receive descriptor */
  void *dma_buffer_tx; /* Kernel virtual address of the transmit descriptor */
  dma_addr_t dma_bus_tx; /* Bus address of the transmit descriptor */
  /* ... */
  spin_lock_t device_lock; /* Serialize */
} *mydev_data;

/* On-card registers related to DMA */
#define DMA_RX_REGISTER_OFFSET 0x0 /* Offset of the register holding the bus address of the RX descriptor */
#define DMA_TX_REGISTER_OFFSET 0x4 /* Offset of the register holding the bus address of the TX descriptor */
#define CONTROL_REGISTER 0x8 /* Offset of the control register */
/* Control Register Defines */
#define INITIATE_XMIT 0x1
/* Descriptor control word definitions */
#define FREE_FLAG 0x1 /* Free Descriptor */
#define INTERRUPT_FLAG 0x2 /* Assert interrupt after DMA */

/* Invoked from Listing 10.3 */
static void dma_descriptor_setup(struct pci_dev *pdev)
{
  /* Allocate receive DMA descriptors and buffers */
  mydev_data->dma_buffer_rx = pci_alloc_consistent(pdev, 3096, &mydev_data->dma_bus_rx);
  /* Fill the two receive descriptors as shown in Figure 10.2 */
  /* RX descriptor 1 */
  mydev_data->dma_buffer_rx[0] = cpu_to_le32((unsigned long)(mydev_data->dma_bus_rx + 24)); /* Buffer address */
  mydev_data->dma_buffer_rx[1] = 1536; /* Buffer length */
  mydev_data->dma_buffer_rx[2] = FREE_FLAG; /* Descriptor is free */
  /* RX descriptor 2 */
  mydev_data->dma_buffer_rx[3] = cpu_to_le32((unsigned long)(mydev_data->dma_bus_rx + 1560)); /* Buffer address */
  mydev_data->dma_buffer_rx[4] = 1536; /* Buffer length */
  mydev_data->dma_buffer_rx[5] = FREE_FLAG; /* Descriptor is free */
  wmb(); /* Write Memory Barrier */
  /* Write the address of the receive descriptor to the appropriate register in the card. The I/O base address, ioaddr, was populated in Listing 10.3 */
  outl(cpu_to_le32((unsigned long)mydev_data->dma_bus_rx), ioaddr + DMA_RX_REGISTER_OFFSET);
  /* Allocate transmit DMA descriptors and buffers */
  mydev_data->dma_buffer_tx = pci_alloc_consistent(pdev, 3096, &mydev_data->dma_bus_tx);
  /* Fill the two transmit descriptors as shown in Figure 10.2 */
  /* TX descriptor 1 */
  mydev_data->dma_buffer_tx[0] = cpu_to_le32((unsigned long)(mydev_data->dma_bus_tx + 24)); /* Buffer address */  <---- line A
  mydev_data->dma_buffer_tx[1] = 1536; /* Buffer length */    <---- line B
  /* Valid descriptor. Generate an interrupt after completing the DMA */
  mydev_data->dma_buffer_tx[2] = (FREE_FLAG | INTERRUPT_FLAG);
  /* TX descriptor 2 */
  mydev_data->dma_buffer_tx[3] = cpu_to_le32((unsigned long)(mydev_data->dma_bus_tx + 1560)); /* Buffer address */
  mydev_data->dma_buffer_tx[4] = 1536; /* Buffer length */
  mydev_data->dma_buffer_tx[5] = (FREE_FLAG | INTERRUPT_FLAG);
  wmb(); /* Write Memory Barrier */
  /* Write the address of the transmit descriptor to the appropriate register in the card. The I/O base, ioaddr, was populated in Listing 10.3 */
  outl(cpu_to_le32((unsigned long)mydev_data->dma_bus_tx), ioaddr + DMA_TX_REGISTER_OFFSET);
}

/* Invoked from Listing 10.3 */
static void dma_descriptor_release(struct pci_dev *pdev)
{
  pci_free_consistent(pdev, 3096, mydev_data->dma_bus_tx);
  pci_free_consistent(pdev, 3096, mydev_data->dma_bus_rx);
}
```

In the code, the driver prepares a buffer for the DMA descriptors and DMA buffers using `pci_alloc_consistent()` and sets them up and passes the buffer address (bus address) to the hardware making sure it's in little endian format using `cpu_to_le32()`. So I understood the H/W sees the buffer descriptor. But in the descriptor, why did it use `cpu_to_le32()` for the descriptor address (line A above) and not for the following buffer length (line B above)? Does the H/W see only the buffer address and not the size? Or is it an error in the book? By the way, this is for a fictitious PCI ethernet chip driver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In practice such approach indeed looks like a mistake. But theoretically it's possible that one field (`address`) is always little endian no matter what, while another (`length`) is in native mode. Nowadays, with help of FPGA, I guess one even may try to implement this theoretical case.

So, in the given context, especially taking into consideration your remark that this is for *a fictitious PCI ethernet chip*, it is a bit hard to say what was author's intention here.